# Как настроить open-wrt к качестве клиента WIFI сети, так чтобы подключенные к роутеру устройства были видны в той сети, к которой подключается роутер?

Tags: администрирование, wifi, роутер, openwrt

Сейчас я роутер настроил в качестве сетевого моста. То есть указал сеть и LAN подключении указал статический адрес роутера 192.168.1.200. Потом у подключенных устройств тоже указал их статические адреса и в качестве шлюза указал 192.168.1.200. Так то все работает, но устройства не доступны из той сети к которой подключен роутер. То есть я вижу в списке WIFI клиентов этот роутер с адресом 192.168.1.200. Возможно ли как то это все настроить так чтобы устройства подключенные к роутеру с open-wrt были доступны так же как будто они подключены в эту общую сеть?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно клиент wifi перевести в зону LAN. Включите режим WDS (4-маковый)